# I need to dynamically Name a Table from spCopyNetworkService SQL Procedure

Tags: c#, sql

```
ALTER PROC spCopyNetworkService
@TableName nvarchar(50)
AS
   EXEC('SELECT * FROM ClientGroups INTO ' + @TableName + '
FROM ClientGroups)');
```

I am using this procedure

```
Running [dbo].[spCopyNetworkService] ( @TableName = 967ea4c-dc38-4d30-a455-a2c1b17d3a83 ).
```

and I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
>
> No rows affected.
>   (0 row(s) returned)
>   @RETURN_VALUE = 0

Finished running [dbo].[spCopyNetworkService].

I just passed it a value and I get this error so it saving the procedure but it isn't working

Comment: add brackets like this: EXEC('SELECT * FROM ClientGroups INTO [' + @TableName + '] FROM ClientGroups)');

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC('select DATAFIELD_VALUE_HERE into [' + @TableName + ']
from ClientGroups)');
```

Comment: What part do I put that in where the into is or just like that alone in the stored procedure

Comment: replace string "SELECT * FROM ClientGroups INTO @TableName WHERE (DATAFIELD_VALUE_HERE) FROM ClientGroups" with EXEC('...')

Comment: Ok that's working partly, It wanting me to pass a value to the current parameter

Comment: That's what I did the stored procedure is working and saved but the @table is requesting a value I have data in my current table that I am copying so is it supposed to get the data from that data field in that table while it copying to name the table with the parameter

Comment: It saves the procedure but the problem is will I have to call the procedure in the application and pass the name of the table through the application when I call the stored procedure cause the table name parameter is coming up null

Comment: I changed it, for some reason it wants a value passed to the parameter @TableName

Comment: The procedure works but its not extracting the value for the parameter from the other table and I am naming the datafield properly as well

Comment: i dont understand - you do not want to pass it ? so how you procedure will know the name of the new table ?

Comment: Well it was suppose to get the name from the ClientGroups table specified datafield, which I was applying in the part we was using the DATAFIELD_VALUE_HERE section of the code. I want all the field values in the new table and as I am getting all the values of the other table I want to use one of those value to specify the table in relation to the table it self so when I transact data to the table it triggers the table name I could pass a value

Comment: I might have to do that, it might be easier just to call the procedure in the application when I am using the transact data table and then pass the value of the analytical table to parameter to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE PROC spCopyNetworkService @TableName nvarchar(50) AS
BEGIN

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName ' SELECT FROM ClientGroups 
WHERE (DATAFIELD_VALUE_HERE)'
EXEC @sql

END
```

Comment: @shawn I eliminated now the DROP TABLES.

Comment: I tried that it gives me a incorrect syntax error for the parameter

Comment: Although this has been answered. This is only for future use purposes. It was an error in the parameter because the parameter '@Tablename' is part of the query itself unlike if it is just only a VALUE to be compared like WHERE ID = @id. So, here you need to put on another variable that would then be executed after using EXEC.